# Django middleware to catch exceptions

Tags: django, exception, middleware

I am trying to create a Django middleware that checks whether the view raised an exception.

Could you give some example of how could there be an exception and how to process that through custom middleware.

In the end I want to store these exceptions in the database.

UPDATE:
I was trying to achieve that with the login process. Which did not work.

Comment: What exceptions are you trying to catch? HTTP? or code? If in code you could catch it via your own logger.

Comment: @Roger I want to catch an exception if the view produces one. It has to be done with a middleware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can try to catch any exceptions in middleware like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve


class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if response.status_code == 500:
            current_url = resolve(request.path_info).view_name
            content = response.content
            ExceptionHandlerModel.objects.create(url = current_url,stacktrace = content, ...) # other data you want to store here
        return response
```

That's about it, it **won't make any sense** unless you store the contents from `response.content`, which is full of **html**. So I think you should **avoid** this solution altogether.

Best approach would be use [logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-loggers). For example in your `loginview`, you can try like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def loginview(request):
    ...
    user = authenticate(username, password)
    if not user:
        logger.error('Username {} failed to login'.format(username))
```

login view not necessarily throws exception either(unless you forcefully throw them). For example:

```
class YourAuthException(Exception):
   # defining a custom exception
   pass

# in view
if not user:
   raise YourAuthException("User login failed")
```

#### Update

```
def get_user(request)

    user = User.objects.get(id=99999999999)  # an id which does not exist in DB
    return HttpResponse("OK GOT IT")
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems the login form wasn't a good approach. Could you suggest another example. I need to catch an exception and save it to the database.

Comment: Well, why don't you catch the exceptions in the views instead? Because middlewares aren't exactly well built for your requirement.

Comment: This is an assignment and they've asked for a middleware

Comment: thanks ,you have been very helpful but I cannot seem to make it work with the login form so I am open to other suggestions of how I can implement that

Comment: As I have said, you can catch the exception if you find `response.status_code == 500`. Please see my implementation on my middleware section.

Comment: @Danae by catching exception, if you meant catching exception by `except Exception`, its not possible to do that in django middleware unfortunately. The best you can do is to store the full stacktrace in html format, which will be available in `response.content` (please see my answer on this)